# convert hexadecimal to decimal in snowflake

Tags: java, hex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I am trying to convert hexadecimal `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` to decimal in snowflake.
expected output is  `340282366920938463463374607431768211455`. (it holds 39 digits)
when i tried using the snowflake java function like below, the output is in exponential format.
The problem is snowflake number data type supports 38 digits.

```
create or replace function js_hextoint (s string) 
returns double language JAVASCRIPT 
 as 
 'if (S !== null)
 {
 output = parseInt(S, 16);
 }
 return output
```

output is `-3.40282366920938e+38`

but the expected output is  `340282366920938463463374607431768211455`.

how can I get the expected decimal conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected output is outside the number range in Snowflake:

```sql
select 340282366920938463463374607431768211455;

-- Error line 1 at position 7 Integer literal is out of representable range: 340282366920938463463374607431768211455
```

You'll notice that you don't get the expected output if you do this outside Snowflake in pure JavaScript too.

But, if you really want to get the number in its full representation -- you can use a Java UDF:

```java
create or replace function java_hextoint (s string) 
returns string 
language java 
handler='MyClass.x'
as $$
import java.math.*;
class MyClass {
  public static String x(String s) {
      return new BigInteger(s, 16).toString();
  }
}
$$;

select java_hextoint('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF');
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.it is so much helpful.

Comment: could you please also help how to compare the numeric string.

Comment: Compare to what? Does it make sense to start a new SO question?

Comment: For pure SQL, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71919022/132438

Answer (score 0):

Felipe Hoffa is very much helpful

Comment: Thanks for this comment. Please accept the answer as it resolves the problem - it's much better than adding an extra answer to say thanks :)